# add field to model using south with django

Tags: django, django-south

I'm using Django and South. my model is:

```
class Msg(models.Model):
        visible         = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        name            = models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

and order of the field in the DB are:

- id
- visible
- name

When i add a new field, ie:

```
class Msg(models.Model):
        visible         = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        default         = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        name            = models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

and use:

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto

python manage.py migrate
```

the order of the field in the DB are:

- id
- visible
- name
- default

how can i get something like the model ?
 - id
 - visible
 - default
 - name

thanks.

Best regards,

Comment: It is totally pointless. I would highly recommend not wasting time on such trivial things which do not add value to the project.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a new table with the column order that you want, most likely. MySQL and PostgreSQL in particular don't reorder column names, and aren't changeable after table creation.

So, create a temp table in the order you want, dump all data, drop the old table, and rename the temp table to be the name you want.

However, unless it's for the sake of your own OCD, there's no real reason to do this.